# DAX measure to count duplicates?

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, dax, business-intelligence

I'm looking for some guidance on how to structure a DAX measure that will count whether a row is a duplicate.

To be counted as a duplicate, the combination of the two columns named: Latitude & Longitude need to be identical. The customers are distinct here.

How would I create a DAX measure called occurrence in Power BI to capture that?

| Customer | Latitude | Longitude | Occurance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 25.2318994 | 89.0194663 | 3 |
| C2 | 25.2318994 | 89.0194663 | 3 |
| C3 | 22.8698924 | 89.0379756 | 2 |
| C4 | 25.2318994 | 89.0194663 | 3 |
| C5 | 22.8698924 | 89.0379756 | 2 |
| C6 | 23.2740535 | 88.0194665 | 1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Occurence = 
    RANKX(
        FILTER(
                'Table',
                'Table'[Latitude]=EARLIER('Table'[Latitude]) &&  'Table'[Longitude]=EARLIER('Table'[Longitude])
                ),
        'Table'[Customer], , DESC
        )
```

Comment: If I use your function, I just get an error - `EARLIER/EARLIEST refers to an earlier row context which doesn't exist.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69623422/how-to-solve-power-bi-earlier-function-error-message

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with `ALLEXCEPT`:

```
Occurrence = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table), ALLEXCEPT(Table, Table[Lat], Table[Lon]))
```

Comment: This is the preferred approach for performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this below measure-

```
Occurrence = 

var curent_row_lat = min(your_table_name_5[Latitude])
var curent_row_lon = min(your_table_name_5[Longitude])

RETURN 
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name_5),
        your_table_name_5[Latitude] = curent_row_lat
            && your_table_name_5[Longitude] = curent_row_lon
    )
)
```

Output-

[image]