# Power BI(DAX) | Getting rows with the same value

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need some help with getting a final status per each ID. The table is sorted by time, and IDs are composed of random alphabets and numbers. Currently a final status is in a string format like below. I created a look up table for each status, converting each status to a numerical value as I wished to be prioritized. What I want is, if operations for an ID has at least one "Complete", I want the table to say "yes", and otherwise(no Complete at all) "no". For example of ID "K304R" below, it operated three times with Status of "Completed", "Error", and "Canceled", and thus the result I want would be a "yes".

My intuition was 1) ALLEXCEPT original table with ID and Status, 2) somehow get rows with the same ID(ex "K304R"), 3) somehow get Status for each rows of "K304R", 4) somehow connect Status back to the look up table, 4) get Max value for statuses, 5) return "yes" if the max value is 100, and otherwise "no".

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks ahead!

**OriginalTable**

| Time | ID | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/10/4 10:47AM | 1ZT56 | Error |
| 2022/10/4 9:47AM | K304R | Completed |
| 2022/10/4 7:47AM | K304R | Canceled |
| 2022/10/3 10:47PM | 1ZT56 | Completed |
| 2022/10/3 7:47AM | PQ534 | Canceled |
| 2022/10/3 4:47AM | 12PT3 | Error |
| 2022/10/2 10:40PM | 12PT3 | Error |
| 2022/10/2 7:47PM | 1ZT56 | Canceled |
| 2022/10/1 10:47AM | U73RL | Completed |

**LookupTable**

| Status | StatusVal |
| --- | --- |
| Completed | 100 |
| Canceled | 0 |
| Error | 0 |

**Result I want**

| Time | ID | Status | FinalStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/10/4 10:47AM | 1ZT56 | Error | yes |
| 2022/10/4 9:47AM | K304R | Completed | yes |
| 2022/10/4 7:47AM | K304R | Canceled | yes |
| 2022/10/3 10:47PM | 1ZT56 | Completed | yes |
| 2022/10/3 7:47AM | PQ534 | Canceled | no |
| 2022/10/3 4:47AM | 12PT3 | Error | no |
| 2022/10/2 10:40PM | 12PT3 | Error | no |
| 2022/10/2 7:47PM | 1ZT56 | Canceled | yes |
| 2022/10/1 10:47AM | U73RL | Completed | yes |

Answer (score 1):

This calculated column works:

```
FinalStatus = 
if(
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS(OriginalTable),
        FILTER(OriginalTable,
            OriginalTable[ID] = EARLIER(OriginalTable[ID]) && 
            OriginalTable[Status]="Completed"))>0,
"Yes","No")
```

The idea is to filter the table for rows where the ID matches the ID in question, then filter for rows where status is "Completed", and then count the remaining rows.

[image]

Comment: I tried, and it gives me an error for EARLIER(OriginalTable[ID]), saying that "Parameter is not the correct type - Cannot find name OriginalTable[ID]". Do you have any suggestion to resolve this issue? @Strictly Funk

Comment: Please verify that you are using a calculated column (not a measure) and that the table and column name match what is in the formula

Comment: I double checked, and I still cannot tell why it isn't working--especially when the first-used OriginalTable[ID] on the left-hand side of the equation doesn't cause any error and it's just the one inside EARLIER.

Comment: Maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69623422/how-to-solve-power-bi-earlier-function-error-message