# DAX or Power Query | Correct value of record based on related records within same table

Tags: dax, powerquery

The problem I'm trying to solve is on a multi-doctor planner database. Due to human error & bad habits, 3 different appointment status indicate **to the user that the appointment actually took place**. Ufortunately, there is an exception, evident only to the user, that takes place whenever a patient has more than one appointment on the same day, with the same doctor.

Case in point, **Fulano de Tal had** a multi stage consult with Dr. Smith on the 9th, starting at 13:30 hrs. The first 2 sessions (APP_IDs 2 and 3) are easily indentified as completed, **but the one at 14:30 hrs had to have taken place**, or would have been outright marked as cancelled. The reason it is known that APP_ID 4 took place is that 2 and 3 were completed. Fulano did not arrive to app_id 5, because it was on the next day, and there was no previous engagement on that day that could be used as a reference.

On the other hand, Pedrito was supposed to have a 3 stage consult with Dr. Doe. Pedrito **did not arrive to APP_ID 6**, but he did arrive for 7 and 8. APP_ID 7 completion is evident, but we only know 8 did so, because it was scheduled on the same day, at a later hour, whereas APP_ID 6 was scheduled before the one we know for certain took place.

| APP_ID | Planner ID | Patient | Date | Date_Time | System Status | Completed? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dr. Smith | Juan Perez | 09-dec-2022 | 09-dec-2022 12:00 | Completed | YES |
| 2 | Dr. Smith | Fulano de Tal | 09-dec-2022 | 09-dec-2022 13:00 | In Consult | YES |
| 3 | Dr. Smith | Fulano de Tal | 09-dec-2022 | 09-dec-2022 13:30 | Waiting | YES |
| 4 | Dr. Smith | Fulano de Tal | 09-dec-2022 | 09-dec-2022 14:00 | Called Upon | **should be YES** |
| 5 | Dr. Smith | Fulano de Tal | 10-dec-2022 | 10-dec-2022 14:30 | Called Upon | **NO** |
| 6 | Dr. Doe | Pedrito | 09-dec-2022 | 09-dec-2022 09:00 | Called Upon | **NO** |
| 7 | Dr. Doe | Pedrito | 09-dec-2022 | 09-dec-2022 09:30 | Completed | YES |
| 8 | Dr. Doe | Pedrito | 09-dec-2022 | 09-dec-2022 10:00 | Called Upon | **should be YES** |

What I need is a calculated column that returns YES whenever:

- The status is either Completed, In Consult or Waiting (this is the easy part)
- The status is Called Upon **AND** the patient **already** had an appointment whose status is one of the above **AND** it took place on the same day **AND** it took place at a later time.

I already tried it on Dax, using a calculated countrows, like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73952279/power-bidax-getting-rows-with-the-same-value), and adding additional conditions within the filter. But I guess because powerbi sorts the table so as to optimize storage, the **earlier()** function does can't properly do a sweep based on dates and time. Therefore, the solution might lie at powerquery, where I can use table.buffer to forcefully sort the table, but what I outright don't know how to do is add the calculated column that makes the full sweep to check for the easy condition and the four less than easy ones.

A solution in either powerquery or with dax work for me.

Please, help me out.

Answer (score 0):

M / Powerquery method

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Date_Time", type datetime}}),
// x[] is current row, [] is entire table 
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", 
(x)=>Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows( #"Changed Type",  each 
        [Patient]=x[Patient] 
        and ([System Status]="Completed" or [System Status]="In Consult" or [System Status]="Waiting") 
        and x[System Status]="Called Upon" 
        and [Date]=x[Date] 
        and [Date_Time]<x[Date_Time]))
),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Completed", each if [System Status]="Completed" or [System Status]="In Consult" or [System Status]="Waiting" or [Custom]>0 then "YES" else "NO"),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Custom"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

**EDITED VERISON**

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

process=(z as table)=> let 
    #"ProcessTable" = Table.AddColumn(z, "Custom", 
    (x)=>Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows( z,  each 
    ([System Status]="Completed" or [System Status]="In Consult" or [System Status]="Waiting") 
    and x[System Status]="Called Upon" 
    and [Date_Time]<x[Date_Time]))
) in #"ProcessTable",

#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Date_Time", type datetime}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Patient", "Date"}, {{"data", each process(_), type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"APP_ID", "Planner ID", "Date_Time", "System Status", "Custom"}, {"APP_ID", "Planner ID", "Date_Time", "System Status", "Custom"}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded data", "Completed", each if [System Status]="Completed" or [System Status]="In Consult" or [System Status]="Waiting" or [Custom]>0 then "YES" else "NO")
in #"Added Custom1"
```

Comment: I'm implementing it, in a filtered table with the data of only one month, and only some of the doctors.

I forgot to add in my example the case when a patient has appointments with more than one doctor, but I guess I only have to add that condition.

As of the moment I'm writing this answer, it might take two hours for the table to load in power BI, as we are talking about a 1,8M+ rows, and PLENTY of columns.

But the preview did not immediately return an error, so, fingers crossed. AND THANKS. You probably saved my mental health.

Comment: thank you for your help @horseyride. Unfortunately, though it seems to work, a it did with a small sample, it seems to be unsustainable. I'm guessing it is because your method does exactly what I wanted, and each row does a full sweep.

After 5 hours, the row count has surpassed 648 million. I'll let it follow its course just to confirm that the actual rows in the table is the expected 1.8+ million, but given the frequency I need to refresh the report, it just takes too long. Do you think a dax solution might be better? Thanks anyway.

Comment: edited code. What if you group on patient and date, then half the work is already done

Comment: Still going to take forever with that many records. See what you get

Comment: I created a "proxy" calculated table with selected column in dax, containing only the relevant data for the comparison, and only the 3 states that mean completed. Then, I attempted a count rows of this table, as long as they fulfill the conditions for my "Called Upon" rows in the original table.

It should have worked, but my PCs resources were not enough to complete the task.

¿is it possible to do something similar in power query?

Or in dax, can I assign a dinamically filteted table to a variable, and compare each row with the columns of said table/variable?

Comment: I've decided to go for another road.

I'm creatinga a REFERENCE of my query, and then select only the columns I want, and the rows with the states I need. However, when refreshing, my reference acceses the source twice. The first time it goes along the original query, and then it goes again. So as to no duplicate the query and all the steps, is there any way I can make sure my reference does no access the source twice?

Comment: Sorry, Im lost at this point perhaps someone else can help

Answer (score 0):

@horseyride

In the end, I went for an auxiliary table. I made a reference query in powerquery, selecting only the states that guarantee the completion of each appointment, and the columns needed to relate the ambiguous consults in the main table.

Although the appointment IDs are not unique, they almost are. So, even though a calculated ditinct count proved to be too much for my machine, a countrows of a filtered table (by the relatable traits) proved quite fast.

Thank you @horseyride.